# springboot logging and masking with logback multiple sensitive data in different log files

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, masking

I am working with logback with springboot project first time; and I have tried to look [references](https://www.baeldung.com/logback-mask-sensitive-data) online. I am dealing with masking sensitive data on different log files.
In this project data is coming from different api endpoints within the same module; I also have different json responses and requests that have data that need masking. I have provided example below.

ACCOUNT module

1. /account/member/list

   ```
   {
       "name": "Apple",
       "email": "behappy@app.com",
       "address": "Elem 4324 5684 USA"
   }
   ```
2. /account/payment/history

```
{
    "first": "Apple",
    "last": "Large",
    "cardNum": "444444444444"
}
```

The masking logic on my logback file looks as follows, and I having two separate log files for the above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    .......
    .......
    <appender name="MEMBER"
        ----
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.fedex.srs.cpg.paymentvalidationapi.filter.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <maskPattern>\"email\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern>
                <maskPattern>\"address\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern>
                <maskPattern>\"cardNum\"\s*:\s*\"([0-9]{14,16})\"</maskPattern> 
                ---10 more similar patterns
            </layout>
        </encoder>
        .......
        .......
    </appender>

    <appender name="PAYMENT"
        ----
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="com.fedex.srs.cpg.paymentvalidationapi.filter.MaskingPatternLayout">
                <maskPattern>\"email\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern>
                <maskPattern>\"address\"\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"</maskPattern>
                <maskPattern>\"cardNum\"\s*:\s*\"([0-9]{14,16})\"</maskPattern> 
                ---10 more similar patterns
            </layout>
        </encoder>
        .......
        .......
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

Above encoder repeated for each appender, and I am only showing two here but I have 6 log files. I repeated Masking layout because
the order of the maskPattern important for my MaskingPatternLayout class to work
I created the class based on baeldung tutorial

```
public class MaskingPatternLayout extends PatternLayout {

    private Pattern multilinePattern;
    private List<String> maskPatterns = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMaskPattern(String maskPattern) {
        maskPatterns.add(maskPattern);
        multilinePattern = Pattern.compile(maskPatterns.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("|")), Pattern.MULTILINE);
    }

    @Override
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        return maskMessage(super.doLayout(event));
    }

    private String maskMessage(String message) {
        if (multilinePattern == null) {
            return message;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
        Matcher matcher = multilinePattern.matcher(sb);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            
            for (int groupIndex = 1; groupIndex <= matcher.groupCount(); groupIndex++)
                if (matcher.group(groupIndex) != null) {// b.subSequence(st, end) != null
                    int st = matcher.start(groupIndex);
                    int end = matcher.end(groupIndex);
                    //each case represent each maskPattern on the logback.xml file
                    switch (groupIndex) {
                    case 1:// email
                    case 2:// address
                        //mask everything
                            break;
                    case 3:// cardNum
                        //I have logic to leave last four characters unmasked
                        break;
                    .......
                    ........
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The logback xml maskPattern order is tightly coupled with the MaskingPatternLayout class switch statement.
My question: Is there a better way of handling this or is my current approach has cost performance wise?  If I have ten patterns only one pattern is associated with one log file, I am still running 9 of those patterns against this one particular file. Is that correct?
In above if I am logging payment information, my logback still running the email and address patterns against the payment log message; if I understand things correctly.
Since it is springboot project, is autowiring Masking class helps for performance?
Maybe I did not understand how things are wired. I need advice on how to approach this. Is the current approach something I can use in production environment?